# How do I reference text boxes from multiple windows in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a note taking application with multiple windows to gather information. How do I save the values of multiple text boxes in multiple windows to variables on button click?

I have successfully implemented it in the MainWindow and I'm having trouble extending the paradigm across multiple windows. I have a feeling it's associated with not assigning a name to the instance of the second window, but I'm not sure how it works.

This is the code for the function that works in the MainWindow:

```
public static void CopyText()
        {
            string srText = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).srBox.Text;
            string contactText = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).contactBox.Text;
            string usernameText = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).usernameBox.Text;
            string generalText = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).generalBox.Text;

            string copyText = "";

            Clipboard.SetDataObject(copyText);
        }
```

This is the code for the function in the CreditWindow that does not work:

```
public static void CopyCreditText()
        {
            string srText = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).srBox.Text;
            string usernameText = ((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).usernameBox.Text;
            string buyerText = ((CreditWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).buyerBox.Text;
            string itemText = ((CreditWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).itemBox.Text;
            string amountText = ((CreditWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).amountBox.Text;
            string typeText = ((CreditWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).typeBox.Text;
            string reasonText = ((CreditWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).reasonBox.Text;

        string copyText = "";

        Clipboard.SetDataObject(copyText);
    }
```

When I run this code, I get an error from Visual Studio on this line:

```
string buyerText = ((CreditWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).buyerBox.Text;
```

that states "Unable to cast object of type 'MSONotes.MainWindow' to type 'MSONotes.CreditWindow'.

Comment: The error kinda says it all `((CreditWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow)`, you're trying to cast a `MainWindow` into a `CreditWindow`.  Try `((CreditWindow)Application.Current.CreditWindow)` instead, but see @BradleyDotNET, you're definitely doing it wrong.

Comment: @BlackICE `MainWindow` is special, I seriously doubt there is a `CreditWindow` property there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because Application.Current.MainWindow is just that, the main window of the entire application. It doesn't change no matter how many child windows exist. It won't become a `CreditWindow`.

Unless the windows have references to each other, you should handle this kind of data passing *well* behind the view layer. I lied, you should do that **regardless**, but references would allow you to keep cheating. In a properly architected application:

- Those text boxes would be bound to fields in a view model
- The button click would push the values to some model (shared by the other window's VMs, ideally using dependency injection)
- Via an event or similar the service would notify all VMs that new data was available
- They would update their own appropriate fields
- The other windows view's would update automatically due to the VM update.

Basically, you are going to need to do WPF properly (with MVVM) and not hack it together like that.

Comment: I appreciate the insight. This is my first time attempting to put anything together in this language/environment and so there's a lot of best practices that I'm naively unaware of still. I'll do some research into View Models and try and structure it correctly. Thank you.

Comment: @SeanEdelen Its a common fallacy in WPF, especially if you come from a WinForms background. Feel free to drop by the WPF chat room if you need help figuring MVVM out.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that a WPF chat room existed and I'll be using that resource moving forward. I spent the weekend studying and I reconfigured the application to run using the MVVM paradigm and everything works perfectly except for animations. I appreciate your help with this!